# phantomJS/highcharts: why 'height' not work

Tags: highcharts, phantomjs

Pass the following config to PhantomJS:

```
{
  u'subtitle': {
    u'text': u'2016-05-19 12:09 to 2016-05-26 12:09'
  },
  u'title': {
    u'text': u'Query'
  },
  u'series': [
  ],
  u'yAxis': {
    u'title': {
      u'text': u'Count'
    }
  },
  u'tooltip': {
    u'pointFormat': u'<span style="color:{point.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>'
  },
  'height': 1000,
  u'credits': {
    u'enabled': False
  },
  u'plotOptions': {
    u'column': {
      u'colorByPoint': False
    }
  },
  u'xAxis': {
    u'type': u'category'
  },
  u'type': u'chart',
  u'legend': {
    u'enabled': True
  }
}
```

but the output PNG is 1200*800? Why? Anything missing?

Thanks

Comment: Your `height` setting is not within the `chart` property object. Also, what is with all the `u`?

Comment: @wergeld chart property object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already **wergeld** answered in comments - `height` is property of `chart` object in the chart's options (see [the API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.height) for a reference). So you could use it like this:

```
{
  'chart': {
    'height': 1000
  },
  'subtitle': {
    'text': '2016-05-19 12:09 to 2016-05-26 12:09'
  },
  ...rest of your settings...
```